# Why is this more specific CSS rule not winning out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a responsive design.  I'm also using a jQuery plugin called [Readmore](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js)

On resizing of the browser window to less than 500 px, I call the following javascript:

```
$('section.abstract').readmore({
        maxHeight: 60,
        speed: 0,
        moreLink: '<a href="#" class="read-more"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="mobile-plus"></i></a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#" class="read-less"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" id="mobile-minus"></i></a>'
      });
```

If the window is above 500 px, then I call the following javascript:

```
$('section.abstract').readmore('destroy');
      $('section.abstract').readmore({
        maxHeight: 60,
        speed: 0,
        moreLink: '<a href="#" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#" class="read-less">Close<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></a>'
      });
    }
```

The insertion of the "read-more" class and i tags seem to be working fine on resize.

But I have 2 pre-defined CSS rules, of which only 1 is being applied.

This is the more specific CSS rule, which should be applied to a mobile size of less than 500 px:

**CSS Rule 1 (more specific)**

```
body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table a.readmore.readmore-js-toggle i#mobile-plus, body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table a.readmore.readmore-js-toggle i#mobile-minus {
      font-size: 3.875em; }
```

This is the less specific CSS rule which keeps being applied at all sizes:

**CSS Rule 2 (less specific)**

```
section.search-results a.readmore-js-toggle i {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Keep in mind that the "a" tag is nested inside the table tag.  Why is the less specific CSS rule always winning?

Does it have something to do with the dynamically injected (via javascript) a and i tags?  I notice when I do a View Source in Firefox browser the "a" and "i" tags don't appear in the source code, although they do when I use the inspector.

EDIT: I also am enclosing CSS Rule 1 in the following media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { .. }
```

Comment: What happens if you switch the order, or use `property: value !important;`?

Comment: Why are you switching out those elements via JS anyway? If showing/hiding the additional link text content at different screen sizes is the goal here, then do _that_ using media queries.

Comment: It's due to the way the way the Readmore plugin works - it has you inject the a and i tags to achieve its functionality.

Comment: Also, the selector `body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table a.readmore.readmore-js-toggle i#mobile-plus` is WAY overqualified. If you have valid HTML, that `mobile-plus` ID should only be there once. So it would help to reduce that selector to just `#mobile-plus` to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table a.readmore.readmore-js-toggle i#mobile-plus, body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table a.readmore.readmore-js-toggle i#mobile-minus {
      font-size: 3.875em; }
```

Can be reduced to:

```
#mobile-minus { font-size: 3.875em; }
```

The following line need to be wrapped in a media query to apply only to sizes at 500px or more:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    section.search-results a.readmore-js-toggle i {
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks, I clarified my post a bit (I was using media query).  Doing this: `body.mobile-display.search-results section.search-results table i#mobile-plus {}` worked